# Android Studio DatePicker class could not be found

Tags: android, android-studio, datepicker

I’m having trouble running my android app ever since I added a DatePicker. I'm running my app using a Virtual Device running Nougat 7.1.1 API level 25, but the app would crash every time I would click on the button that allows the user to pick a date. My app gives me a pop up saying that the app has stopped working whenever I would try and click on the button to pick a date. Also, in my dialog_date.xml preview, it gives me the following error (screen shot right below). I've already tried clicking on the tips. Do I need to add any dependencies in my build.gradle file for the DatePicker to be found? I've been trying to figure this out for 3 hours now.

[image]

Below I have posted my build.gradle, DatePickerFragment.java, and dialog_date.xml.

**dialog_date.xml** 
[image]

**build.gradle file** 
[image]

**DatePickerFragment.java**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you think `android.support.constraint.DatePicker` exists. The [documentation for `DatePicker`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html) shows it as `android.widget.DatePicker`.